# Is there a way to combine several ODBC Connections to use one login instead of one for each connection?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I have Excel 365 ProPlus where I have 1 workbook with 5 separate ODBS Connections. When I refresh all that requires the user to enter the same login data 5 separate times for each one. I set up some VB Code so the end user enters their login info 1 time into a form. Then it refreshes each data sheet but I can't seem to pass the login form data to the refresh because it just asks them to enter their login data again. I just need some guidance. On one hand I could set the VB Code to create the data connection everytime a user opens the workbook. This way I can control all of the parameters in VBA but surely there is a way to use my existing connections and refresh while passing the login data from the form. Any Ideas?

````
Dim UserID As String, Pword As String, SystemAccess As String


Sub Refresh()

Dim Svr As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset

    'Control events in screen
    'ActiveSheet.Select
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next

    If SystemAccess = "True" Then
        Svr.Open "provider=IBMDA400;data source=137.168.234.245;User ID=" & UserID & "; Password=" & Pword
    Sheets("EDV001P - PM").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Range("A2").Select

    Rs.Open "Select * From EDV002P", Svr
    Sheets("EDV002P - PO").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Rs.RecordCount

    Rs.Open "Select * From EDV003P", Svr
    Sheets("EDV003P - AP").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Rs.RecordCount

    Rs.Open "Select * From EDV005P", Svr
    Sheets("EDV005P - Ind Cost").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Rs.RecordCount
    Else
        MsgBox "Verify your credentials"
        Call Access
    End If

    If Err Then
        MsgBox Error
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
    Svr.Close
    Set Svr = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox ("Complete, Have a Semi Awesome Day") 
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
Rs.Open "Select * From EDV002P", Svr
Sheets("EDV002P - PO").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Rs.RecordCount
```

would be better as:

```
Rs.Open "Select count(*) From EDV002P", Svr
Sheets("EDV002P - PO").Range("A2").Value = Rs.Fields(0).Value
```

If you just need a count then no need to do that client-side.

Also - if you just need to refresh some tables of data from the database, you can query the data as you already do for your counts, then drop it onto your worksheet using `CopyFromRecordset`